# PowerBI - How to hide rows where results are all 0's

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm still very new to PowerBI and learning as I go.

I'm making a report for user permissions and want to hide the rows where someone has no permissions for a screen, where its all 0's but want to see the row if it as at least one '1' in it.

I've done some searching but can't find how to do it.

[image: Here is an example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Blank instead of 0 this will happen automatically.  Otherwise write a measure like

```
MaxValue = max('Table'[Column2]) + max('Table'[Column3]) + max('Table'[Column4])
```

And use it in a visual-level filter.

Comment: Perfect. I created the measure and added it to the table, then filtered greater than 0 to hide the row.
I have a lot to learn when it comes to the trick like this.